# Registry Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to set up the custom registry file for my codeigniter project but can not seem to fin best places to set the get instance

I am trying to convert my **oop** to **codeigniter**.

```
final class Registry {
    private $data = array();

    public function get($key) {
        return (isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : null);
    }

    public function set($key, $value) {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function has($key) {
        return isset($this->data[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Registry library for CodeIgniter :- https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-registry

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need. But placing the exact same code in a library is the easiest way you can get going.

Save the file as `registry.php` in `applications/libraries`

Then you can load the library using `$this->load->library('registry');`

If your question is about storing data persistently, then try using `static`. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) the reference.